# Code produces Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I've got the following code:

```
public static void pauseAllTimers() {
        for(Timer timer : Timer.allTimers) {
            timer.pause();

        }

    }
```

Where `Timer` instances are being added and removed to `allTimers` within one thread (as far as I can tell, unless I'm overseeing something in my code).

Why is my code yielding a Concurrent Modification Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *iterating* over the collection while you're removing from it - assuming that `pause()` removes the timer. Don't do that - you're modifying a collection while you're still iterating over it, which is a concurrent modification even though there's only one thread.

Copy the set of timers to a list, and then iterate over *that*:

```
List<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>(Timer.allTimers);
for (Timer timer : timers) {
    timer.pause();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, however I am not removing or adding any instance to the allTimerlist during the pause method.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: So when you say "Where Timer instances are being added and removed to allTimers within one thread" - what's doing that? Is this your own `Timer` class? (I don't remember ever seeing an `allTimers` field on `java.util.Timer`...)

Comment: My apologies, I am removing an instance from the allTimerlist in the pause method. It was another method that I was calling within the pause method that does this. Yes, this is my own Timer class which belongs to my Game Engine I'm writing. Thank you for your answer.